# Bibliography conforming to "ISO 690" standard using natbib in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have searched a lot about ma problem and did not get any fruitful results. So i hopefully get the help here.
I am using natbib package for reference citation. I would like to get the bibliography list in **"DIN ISO 690"** style, as it is required for my thesis work in this format to submit in university. I am using english language. More information regarding DIN ISO can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sYDrkkEHQ-QTFQOTdJMk5QWms/view?usp=sharing), it's originally in German and English version is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sYDrkkEHQ-cWZ0aVpXMUM4YW8/view?usp=sharing). I am not aware of biblatex package, so not using it and time is really short for submission.

**Does anybody know how can I get the DIN ISO-690 format in LaTeX using natbib package?** How can I change the bibliographystyle to DIN ISO-690? Thanks in advance

My sample code is as follows with used packages and bib file,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
% packages
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[notintoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passages
%\usepackage{ngerman} % needed for German default language
\usepackage{amsmath} % needed for command eqref
\usepackage{amssymb} % needed for math fonts
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
    %,ngerman
    ]{hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the document, the option colorlinks=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonkg links (list of figures), and ngerman sets everything for german as default hyperlinks language
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} % ben�tigt f�r das Brechen von URLs in Literaturreferenzen, hyphenbreaks auch bei links, die �ber eine Seite gehen (mit hyphenation).
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} % blue
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9} % light blue
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}
\usepackage{cite} % needed for cite
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliography style
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for \includegraphics 
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{todonotes} % needed for todos
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Someone name some man, \citet{farrar2007introduction}. \\ woman....\citet{castillo2009unified}......asölwnd......\citet{herrmann2014structural}....... SHM-Automotive..........\citet{smith2007introduction}........ \citet{wenzel2008health}.........

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}    
\bibliography{sample_lib}

\end{document}
```

Following is an sample bib file created using citavi software for reference management.

```
    % This file was created with Citavi 5.2.0.8

@book{adams2007health,
 author = {Adams, D.},
 year = {2007},
 title = {Health Monitoring of Structural Materials and Components: Methods with Applications},
 publisher = {Wiley},
 isbn = {9780470511572}
}

@book{castillo2009unified,
 author = {Castillo, Enrique and Fern{\'a}ndez-Canteli, Alfonso.},
 year = {2009},
 title = {A unified statistical methodology for modeling fatigue damage},
 keywords = {Fatigue;Materials;Mathematical models},
 address = {Abington},
 publisher = {Springer},
 isbn = {9781402091827}
}


@article{farrar2007introduction,
 author = {Farrar, C. R. and Worden, K.},
 year = {2007},
 title = {An introduction to structural health monitoring},
 pages = {303--315},
 volume = {365},
 number = {1851},
 issn = {1364-503X},
 journal = {Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences}
}


@incollection{herrmann2014structural,
 author = {Herrmann, S. and Wellnitz, J. and Jahn, S. and Leonhardt, S.},
 title = {Structural Health Monitoring for Carbon Fiber Resin Composite Car Body Structures},
 pages = {75--96},
 publisher = {{Springer International Publishing}},
 isbn = {978-3-319-01883-6},
 series = {Lecture Notes in Mobility},
 editor = {Wellnitz, J{\"o}rg and Subic, Aleksandar and Trufin, Ramona},
 booktitle = {Sustainable Automotive Technologies 2013},
 year = {2014},
 address = {Cham},
 doi = {\url{10.1007/978-3-319-01884-3{\textunderscore }8}}
}

 @book{smith2007introduction,
 author = {Smith, J. O.},
 year = {2008},
 title = {Introduction to Digital Filters: With Audio Applications},
 publisher = {W3K},
 isbn = {9780974560717}
}


@book{wenzel2008health,
 author = {Wenzel, H.},
 year = {2008},
 title = {Health Monitoring of Bridges},
 publisher = {Wiley},
 isbn = {9780470740187}
}
```

Comment: @Mico updated the description of link regarding citation standard DIN ISO 690 in main question. After checking out, Please let me know, if u know the answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer to report what I've learned about the standard. Since it costs $150 to download the standard, I've decided not to look into the material details of the standard.

Comment: I've taken a look at the material in the two links. I don't think that the information provided there is in any way authoritative. Instead, they appear to be one person's interpretation of the standard. For sure, the formatting elements cannot possibly be based on the standard itself.

Comment: Since i am foreign student in Germany. Its German Standard for citation recommended by German Industries and Universities, so i am sure its standard.

Comment: "It's [a] German Standard for citation recommended by German Industries and Universities". Then, please, provide a direct reference to a document which doesn't appeal to or references ISO690: As I've tried to demonstrate in my answer, the ISO standard makes *no prescriptions regarding style and punctuation*.

Comment: Please refer to the following links.... http://www.din.de/en/getting-involved/standards-committees/nid/standards/wdc-beuth:din21:190805484 , http://wiki.aki-stuttgart.de/mediawiki/index.php/DIN#DIN_ISO_690

Comment: I am not declaring my personal favorite as STANDARD, DIN ISO-690 is followed most of reputed university in Germany, Technical University Munich and my university University of Applied Science Ingolstadt ( Association of AUDI)...anywayz thanks for the help. I found BibTex package in DIN ISO-690, if someone wants can refer the following link. https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690

Comment: Please re-read what I've written: I have *not* stated in any way that one of the links you've provided embodies your personal favorite style. What I have stated -- and what I continue to stand by -- is that it appears to be *inaccurate* to claim that ISO 690 has any direct implications for formatting or punctuation. Of course, if you find some style that you believe addresses your formatting needs, go ahead and use it, by all means.

Comment: For all those who are in Germany and want to cite DIN ISO-690 for their thesis work or article, this is the perfect link and ready to use. https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690

Answer (score 2):

The [ISO 690 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_690) claims that this standard concerns the required elements, or *inputs*, of a bibliographic reference, and that it is not concerned with the formatting of the typeset output. If this information is correct, it doesn't make much sense to talk about an ISO690-compliant BibTeX or biblatex style: Just about all BibTeX and biblatex styles that don't drop fields that are required according to the standard will automatically be OK.

Similarly, on the [ISO 690:2010(en)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:690:ed-3:v1:en) page, one finds the following passage: "This International Standard does not prescribe a particular style of reference or citation. The examples used in this International Standard are not prescriptive as to style and punctuation."

Thus, all you need to do at this stage is to make sure (a) that none of your bib entries are missing any required fields and (b) that whatever BibTeX or biblatex style you employ doesn't drop any of the required fields.

Comment: By the way, the pdf file containing the details of the ISO 690 standard isn't free of charge. In fact, appears to cost about $150 [!] to download. Unsurprisingly, I haven't sprung for the  cost of this document...

Comment: Unfortunately, there seem to be many people (in a position of power) out there that just declare a certain bibliography style they like to be *the* ISO 690 style and fore people to follow it to the letter.

Comment: @moewe - I fully agree with your view. It's rather unfortunate that some people get to declare their personal favorite formatting style to be *the* style that must be adopted by others -- and then try to give their stylistic preference a sense of generality and respectability by claiming that it implements some ISO standard which, upon closer reading, imposes no formatting or punctuation constraints whatsoever.